# Running a C# exe without .NET 3.5 Windows feature activated

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a C# exe called `fixwsdl.exe` which is written in .NET 3.5 which is used to parse and modify some files. It runs successfully on a Windows 2016 build machine which has .NET 3.5 Windows feature activated. The exe is specified in our csproj file.

Now for infra issues we have to move to different build machine which does not have 3.5 Windows feature installed but has .NET 3.5 related binaries downloaded in a different path. (For example the C# Referenced assemblies like `mscorlib.dll` etc are downloaded to `C:\Projects\.net3.5\ReferencedLibraries`).

Below is the way the C# exe gets executed in our csproj file:

```xml
<Message Text="Fixing WSDLs" Importance="Normal" />
    <Exec Command="$(TCROOT)\Win32\fixwsdl-1.0-vc80\bin\fixwsdl.exe " WorkingDirectory="$(TargetDir)" />
```

Is there any command line arguments that can be added in the above line to make `fixwsdl.exe` execute successfully even though 3.5 Windows feature is not activated?

Just adding a couple of findings. When I try to run fixwsdl.exe manually with .NET 3.5 feature enabled it runs as expected. If .NET 3.5 feature is disabled, I get a popup saying trying to install 3.5.

Just want to know if its possible to run the fixwsdl.exe from our csproj file without activating .NET 3.5.

Comment: my understanding is that "activating" .net makes some exes and dlls available. If these are already downloaded in my system, can't we run the exe by providing the path to the dependant libraries etc without activating .net 3.5 windows feature

Comment: If you want to run a .NET 3.5 application, the target PC you want to run it on **must have** .NET 3.5 installed - no way around that. (don't really know what you mean by "activated" - once .NET 3.5 is installed, it's there and ready to be used - there's no specific "activation" step AFAIK)

Comment: By "activated" I mean clicking .net framework 3.5 features in the windows Add Roles and Features wizard

Comment: Activating a feature - is not just _"makes some exes and dlls available"_. Do you have a sources of this `fixwsdl.exe`? Or why don't you just activate this feature on new machine?

Comment: why don't you just activate this feature on new machine? --For this I will have to take approval from infra team as the build machine changes needs to be approved by them. Hence before that I wanted to check if anyway it can be run without activating this feature. Looks like we can't